# Java 8 Streams for String manipulation

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I want to perform multiple tasks on a single string. 
I need to get a string and extract different sub-strings using a delimiter (`"/"`), then reverse the list of sub-strings and finally join them using another delimiter (`"."`) such that `/tmp/test/hello/world/` would turn into: `world.hello.test.tmp`

Using Java 7 the code is as follows:

```
String str ="/tmp/test/";
List<String> elephantList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split("/")));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=elephantList.size()-1; i>-1; i--) {
    String a = elephantList.get(i);
    if (a.equals(""))
    {
        elephantList.remove(i);
    }
    else
    {
        sb.append(a);
        sb.append('.');
    }
}
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
System.out.println("result" + elephantList + "   " + sb.toString());
```

I was wondering how I could do the same thing using Java 8 streams and the join function it has for Strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to collect the terms into a list, reverse the list and join on the new delimiter:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;

List<String> terms = Pattern.compile("/")
        .splitAsStream(str)
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));

Collections.reverse(terms);

String result = String.join(".", terms);
```

You can do it without collecting into an intermediate list but it will be less readable and not worth the trouble for practical purposes.

Another issue to consider is that your strings appear to be paths.  It is usually better to use `Path` class rather than splitting by "/" manually.  Here's how you would do this (this approach also demonstrates how to use `IntStream` over indexes to stream over a list backwards):

```
Path p = Paths.get(str);

result = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, p.getNameCount())
        .map(i -> p.getNameCount() - i)  // becomes a stream of count-1 to 0
        .mapToObj(p::getName)
        .map(Path::toString)
        .collect(joining("."));
```

This will have the advantage of being OS-independent.

Comment: wondering whether you had the reduction in mind, when you wrote "less readable". `reduce((s1, s2) -> String.join(".", s2, s1))` to me seems to be as readable as `collect`, then `reverse` and then `join` :-)

Comment: Using `Path` is OS independent, if the task really is to replace separator characters of the default `FileSystem` and not `'/'` specifically, as asked for in the question. If we’re talking, e.g. about URI parts or ZIP file entries, this might not be the correct solution (and actually *adding* an os dependency).

Comment: @Holger, you are right, that's why I hedged and said that it's "usually" better to use `Path`.  I don't know the context of the question, so I felt it would be good to show both approaches.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want an intermediate list and just want to join the `String` reversely:

```
String delimiter = ".";
Optional<String> result = Pattern.compile("/")
                                 .splitAsStream(str)
                                 .filter(s -> ! s.isEmpty())
                                 .reduce((s, s2) -> String.join(delimiter, s2, s));
```

Or just use `.reduce((s1, s2) -> s2 + '.' + s1);` as it is probably as readable as `String.join(".", s2, s1);` (thanks Holger for the suggestion).

From then on you could do one of the following:

```
result.ifPresent(System.out::println); // print the result
String resultAsString = result.orElse(""); // get the value or default to empty string
resultAsString = result.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("not a valid path?")); // get the value or throw an exception
```

Another way using `StreamSupport` and `Spliterator` (inspired by Mishas suggestion to use a `Path`):

```
Optional<String> result = StreamSupport.stream(Paths.get(str).spliterator(), false)
                                       .map(Path::getFileName)
                                       .map(Path::toString)
                                       .reduce((s, s2) -> s2 + '.' + s);
```

Of course you can simplify it by omitting the intermediate `Optional`-object and just call your desired method immediately:

```
stream(get(str).spliterator(), false)
    .map(Path::getFileName)
    .map(Path::toString)
    .reduce((s, s2) -> s2 + '.' + s)
    .ifPresent(out::println); // orElse... orElseThrow
```

in the last example you would add the following static imports:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.nio.file.Paths.get;
import static java.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream;
```

Comment: Is `(s, s2) -> String.join(delimiter, s2, s)` really a win over `(s1, s2) -> s2+delimiter+s1`?

Comment: good point! `s2 + '.' + s1` would definitely also do it... didn't question that usage ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your Java 7 code isn’t what I’d call a straight-forward solution.
This is, how I would implement it in Java 7:

```
String str = "/tmp/test/";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length()+1);
for(int s=str.lastIndexOf('/'), e=str.length(); e>=0; e=s, s=str.lastIndexOf('/', e-1)) {
    if(s+1<e) sb.append(str, s+1, e).append('.');
}
if(sb.length()>0) sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
System.out.println("result " + sb);
```

and thinking about it again, this is also how I’d implement it in Java 8, as using the Stream API doesn’t really improve this operation.

Comment: it's probably a matter of taste... I think this solution requires more attention from the reader... I need to read the whole code to understand what's going on... in the stream solution I rather can check (step by step) the `map`, `reduce` and/or `collect` parameters.

Comment: @Roland: So far, I did not see a convincing Stream based solution that would allow such easy reading. I’d consider Misha’s solution using `Collections.reverse` readable, but this isn’t a Stream operation either. Of course, in a real application, you’d put my code into a named method and create some unit test cases…

Comment: maybe I became a _`Stream`-fanboy_ and that is why I find `map(Path::getFileName).map(Path::toString).reduce((s1, s2) -> s2 + '.' + s1);` as readable as putting it in an intermediate list... moving hard-to-understand code into named methods is probably always a good idea ;-) (regardless of which solution is applied)... so still... it's a matter of taste... (and performance). :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this :

```
String newPath = Arrays.asList(path.split("/")).stream()
            .filter(x -> !x.isEmpty())
            .reduce("",(cc,ss)->{
                if(!cc.isEmpty())
                    return ss+"."+cc;
                else return ss;
            },(s1,s2)->s2+s1);
```

The filter eliminates first backslash and reduce method has to control if there are any other last empty strings.